# Conditionally Include and ThenInclude

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-core

As commonly known in EF-Core there is no Lazy loading. So that kind of means I'm forced to do my queries with some afterthought. So since I have to think, then i might as well try to do it properly.

I have a Fairly standard update query, but I thought hey, I don't always have to include the `HeaderImage` and `PromoImage` FK-objects. There should be a way to make that happen. But I can just not find a way to perform a Include at a later point. In-fact I would like to maybe include right before I actually do work on the object. That way i might be able to automate some of the eagerness.

```
ArticleContent ac = _ctx.ArticleContents
    .Include(a=> a.Metadata)
    .Include(a=> a.HeaderImage)
    .Include(a=> a.PromoImage)
    .Single(a => a.Id == model.BaseID);

ac.Title = model.Title;
ac.Ingress = model.Ingress;
ac.Body = model.Body;
ac.Footer = model.Footer;

if (model.HeaderImage != null)
{
    ac.HeaderImage.FileURL = await StoreImage(model.HeaderImage, $"Header_{model.Title.Replace(" ", "_")}_{rand.Next()}");
}
if (model.PromoImage != null)
{
    ac.PromoImage.FileURL = await StoreImage(model.PromoImage, $"Promo_{model.Title.Replace(" ", "_")}_{rand.Next()}");
}

ac.Metadata.EditedById = uId;
ac.Metadata.LastChangedTimestamp = DateTime.Now;

await _ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
```

**EXTRA**

To be clear, this is **EF7 (Core)**, and im after a solution that allows me to add includes on demand, hopefully after the initial `_ctx.ArticleContents.Include(a=> a.Metadata).Single(a => a.Id == model.BaseID).`

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to do it after you've called Single - this will materialize the object from the database into memory, taking into account all the Includes that you have specified up to that point. To be able to do it after the fact would be to ask the framework to fetch additional data on top of that which it has already read (i.e. you're trying to force lazy loading into an eager loading approach)

Comment: @MikeGoatly Yes, I'm afraid thats the best answer, my dream solution would be a hybrid between eager and lazy loading. there should exist something like `IncludeIf(a=>a.PromoImage, true|false)` that would really be a fairly optimal solution to my dream

Answer (score 2):

I'm using something similar to Alexander Derck's solution. (Regarding the exception mentioned in the comments: ctx.ArticleContents.AsQueryable() should also work.)

For a couple of CRUD MVC sites I'm using a `BaseAdminController`. In the derived concrete Controllers I can add Includes dynamically. From the BaseAdminController:

```
// TModel: e.g. ArticleContent
private List<Expression<Func<TModel, object>>> includeIndexExpressionList = new List<Expression<Func<TModel, object>>>();

protected void AddIncludes(Expression<Func<TModel, object>> includeExpression)
{
    includeIndexExpressionList.Add(includeExpression);
}
```

Later I saw that I need more flexibility, so I added a queryable. E.g. for ThenInclude().

```
private Func<IQueryable<TModel>, IQueryable<TModel>>  IndexAdditionalQuery { get; set; }

protected void SetAdditionalQuery(Func<IQueryable<TModel>, IQueryable<TModel>> queryable)
{
    IndexAdditionalQuery = queryable;
}
```

Here the Index action:

```
public virtual async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    // dynamic include:
    // dbset is for instance ctx.ArticleContents
    var queryable = includeIndexExpressionList
        .Aggregate(dbSet.AsQueryable(), (current, include) => current.Include(include));
    if(IndexAdditionalQuery != null) queryable = IndexAdditionalQuery(queryable);
    var list = await queryable.Take(100).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
    var viewModelList = list.Map<IList<TModel>, IList<TViewModel>>();

    return View(viewModelList);
}
```

In the concrete Controller I use:

```
AddIncludes(e => e.EventCategory);

SetAdditionalQuery(q => q
    .Include(e => e.Event2Locations)
    .ThenInclude(j => j.Location));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a method to fetch the data which takes the properties to include as expressions:

```
static ArticleContent GetArticleContent(int ID, 
   params Expression<Func<ArticleContent, object>>[] includes)
{
   using(var ctx = new MyContext())
   {
      var acQuery =  _ctx.ArticleContents.Include(a=> a.Metadata);
      foreach(var include in includes)
        acQuery = acQuery.Include(include);
      return acQuery.Single(a => a.Id == model.BaseID);
   }
}
```

And then in main method:

```
var ac = GetArticleContent(3, a => a.HeaderImage, a => a.PromoImage);
```

Comment: Hmm, that's fairly close to what I was hoping for it s still a little "locked", but it breaks on `acQuery.Include(include)` The error is `Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.IIncludableQueryable<TechNews.Models.Entity.ArticleContent, object>' to 'Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.IIncludableQueryable<TechNews.Models.Entity.ArticleContent, TechNews.Models.Entity.GeneralMetadata>'` tried some "workarounds" but to no avail.

Comment: Removing GeneralMetadata yields just `Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.IIncludableQueryable<TechNews.Models.Entity.ArticleContent, object>' to 'Microsoft.Data.Entity.DbSet<TechNews.Models.Entity.ArticleContent>'`

Comment: @ThomasAndreèLian Just tried it in my own db and it works, are you sure you have `System.Data.Entity` referenced? Also I get the error you have without the first include (not in the foreach), I can resolve it by doing `var acQuery = ctx.ArticleContents.Select(a => a);`

Comment: Its EF-Core A.K.A EF7 so its Microsoft.Data.Entity not System.Data.Entity